# Text filtering from configuration file

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, grep, icinga2

We have a config file which consists of more than 24000 lines.

I am stuck in one task. I need to segregate the lines starting as below (service definition of specific host in icinga2)

```
     Object Service "<host_name>"{
```

And ending with

```
      }
```

Files consists multiple other entries as well

I need to filter specific hosts definition  alone.

Comment: Check `jq` utility as icinga configs are `JSON` files

Answer (score 0):

Very simple `sed` approach:

```
sed -n '/incinga2/,/}/p' file
```

You might be better off with the commented on tools (`jq`) if the file's structure becomes more complicated, though.